# AWS host not sending email using email account of bluehost

Tags: spring, email, amazon-web-services, shared-hosting

I have my java website hosted on AWS and i have domain and email account on Bluehost. AWS shows `550 Access Denied - Invalid Helo name`.. when i send email.

is it normal or we have to host domain on AWS for sending emails?